# MariaDB functions cannot correctly retrieve data from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-function, information-schema

I want to create a function in SQL that takes in a field name and field type and returns a boolean value. Based on the result, I will decide whether or not to update the field type. Here is the code for debug:

```
use teleport;
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS check_column_data_type;
CREATE FUNCTION check_column_data_type(table_name VARCHAR(255), column_name VARCHAR(255), data_type VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS longtext
BEGIN
    DECLARE column_type longtext;
    SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(DATA_TYPE)
            INTO column_type
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE
                TABLE_SCHEMA = "teleport" 
                AND TABLE_NAME = "tp_order"   -- use special string for test
                AND COLUMN_NAME = "content";
    -- IF LOWER(column_type) = LOWER(data_type) THEN
    --     RETURN(TRUE);
    -- ELSE
    --     RETURN(FALSE);
    -- END IF;
    RETURN(column_type);   -- just show the content of column_type
END //

DELIMITER ;

select check_column_data_type('tp_order', 'content', 'varchar(10240)');
```

But the output is really puzzling, long and repeat:

```
MariaDB [teleport]> source /home/teleport/www/teleport/teleport_update.sql
... ... 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240),varchar(10240)
... ...
```

The strange thing is not only the results. When I query COLUMN_TYPE in the function, it return NULL, but it work normally when I query it in Navicat. In the function, I have to use DATA_TYPE. What could be the problem? Is my implementation approach for this functionality correct?

If I don't use function, just query using navicat. The result is correct:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( COLUMN_TYPE )
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = "teleport" 
    AND TABLE_NAME = "tp_order" 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = "content";
```

RESULT:
varchar(1024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your query returns the datatype for one column in one table you do not need the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The actual problem is that you are using parameter names that are the same as the column names. Use a prefix (like 'in_') to separate the parameters from the column names:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS check_column_data_type
//
CREATE FUNCTION check_column_data_type(
in_table_name VARCHAR(255),
in_column_name VARCHAR(255),
in_data_type VARCHAR(255)
) 
RETURNS longtext
BEGIN
DECLARE column_type longtext;
SELECT DATA_TYPE INTO column_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = database() 
  AND TABLE_NAME = in_table_name   -- use special string for test
  AND COLUMN_NAME = in_column_name;
    -- IF LOWER(column_type) = LOWER(data_type) THEN
    --     RETURN(TRUE);
    -- ELSE
    --     RETURN(FALSE);
    -- END IF;
RETURN(column_type);   -- just show the content of column_type
END
```

Comment: Great, indeed my parameter names were conflicting with keywords. I also wanted to ask, I am familiar with Python programming, but this issue has been bothering me for a long time. Could you please advise me on how to debug and resolve similar problems in the future? Or are there any resources available to learn MySQL function programming? Thank you once again for your response!